# Matching similar but not exact text strings in Excel VBA projects

Tags: string, excel, vba, merge, match

Okay, I have been trying to find a solution for this and I just don't seem to be able. I can't even break down the problem properly. This is the idea.

I have two sheets with many rows (one with 800 and the other with 300,000). Each row contains a Name column and then several columns that contain information about this Name. Each sheet has different kinds of information.

I want to consolidate these two sheets into a master sheet based on this Name column they both have, so the consolidate function is perfect for this. Now the problem is that the names don't match perfectly.

For example Sheet1 contains

"Company B.V.", "Info #1" 
"Company Total", "Info #2" 
"Company Ltd", "Info #3"

and sheet 2 contains

"Company and Co.", "Info #4" 
"Company and Co", "Info #5"

Sheet 1 contains all the names that are going to be used (around a 100 but in different forms as stated above) and sheet 2 contains all these 100 in multiple rows plus names that aren't in the 100 list and therefore I don't care about.

How would I make a VBA code project where the end result would be something like this, Master sheet:

"Company", "Info #1", "Info #2", "Info #3", "Info #4", "Info #5"

for every single "Company" (the 100 list) in there??

I do hope there is a solution for this. I'm pretty new to VBA projects, but I have done some minimal coding before.

Comment: You need to decide what rules make "Company B.V." the same as "Company and Co." then apply them to make the conversion. E.g. is it always the 1st word? or what's left after replacing a set of words (b.v./total/and co.)? ... if you cant articulate that, you wont be able to get excel to do it.

Comment: You have to set **some kind** of criteria for what "similar enough" means... For example, would it be OK to just match based upon the first word between the 2 sheets??

Comment: Yes you are both right, unfortunately, first word isn't an option. Is there a possibility to find a minimal length of characters that match between two strings, and use that as the "Company" name, i.e. a whole word should match perfectly, including the space before and after.

Comment: What about all words larger than 4 characters within one cell should match exactly? Is that a 'makable' condition?

Comment: ... Given your example above, the cell with `Company Total` would have failed the 4-char criteria, so make sure you're happy with that, but if you were ok, I would write a simple VBA function that takes a cell (or string) and an integer (for the number of charecters to match) as inputs. It would then examine each word in that string - If it is longer than the required number of characters, then append it onto an output string - then you could compare the 2 cells' values once they've moved through this function... Only challenge is if the words are in different order in the cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would place the macro in your PERSONAL section, this way the macro is available in all worksheets. Do this by recording a dummy macro and select to store it in Personal Macro workbook. Now you can manually add new macro's and functions in this personal workbook.

I just tried this one (don't know the original source) and it works fine.

The formula looks like this: =PERSONAL.XLSB!FuzzyFind(A1,B$1:B$20)

The code is here:

```
Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
For Each cell In tbl_array
  str = cell
  For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
    If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
      a = a + 1
      cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid(cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
  Next i
  a = a - Len(cell)
  If a > b Then
    b = a
    Value = str
  End If
  a = 0
Next cell
FuzzyFind = Value
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code! Is it possible to return nothing (blank cell) if no match larger than (for example) 4 characters or more from the lookup value is found?

Answer (score 3):

You can Google Excel UDF Fuzzy lookup or Levensthein distance. There are some UDF's floating around and Microsoft does have a Fuzzy lookup/match add-on as well (when I used it, it was crash prone and not intuitive).

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need, but I get a compile error ("Variable not defined"), exactly like int this post: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/64987-comparing-two-columns.html

Answer (score 3):

I used Robert solution and it works fine for me. I am posting whole solution for people who are new for excel but knows coding:

Though this thread is old but I took some code from another threads and tried and looks like solution is giving approx match. Here I am trying to match one column of sheet1 with one column of sheet2:

1. add command button in excel
2. put following code and click/run button and function gives you result in selected column

```vb
 Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim LRow As Long, i As Long, lval As String


   '~~> Change this to the relevant worsheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    '~~> Find Last Row in Col G which has data
    LRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If LRow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in column D"
    Else
        For i = 2 To LRow


             lval = "D"
            .Range("G" & i).Value = FuzzyFind(lval & i, .Range("PWC"))
        Next i
    End If
    End With

    End Sub


    Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
    Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant

    For Each cell In tbl_array
     str = cell
     For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
      If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
     a = a + 1
     cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid   (cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
     Next i
     a = a - Len(cell)
     If a > b Then
       b = a
       Value = str
    End If
       a = 0
    Next cell
      If Value <> "" Then
         FuzzyFind = Value
      Else
         FuzzyFind = "None"
      End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the functions on [this DDoE post](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/09/13/string-diffing/).  You could generate a longest common sequence string and compare the length to the original string.  Feed it some known matches and some close non-matches and see if you can see a clear dividing line between them.

These functions are used for diffing, not finding close matches, but they may work for you.

Comment: The functions look very usable for my issue. If I have two different strings I would like to match to each other, I would use the LCSTable first and use that table as input for the LCSString function?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly on point but similar, and people dealing with ***my*** issue are likely to find ***this*** page when searching.

**Task:** A list of patients who have been in car wrecks, including street addresses.  Find related accounts based on same street address.  The list will be a maximum of maybe 120 records--so ***partial*** manual review is realistic.

**Problem:** Street addresses are similar but not identical, e.g. 123 JONES LANE and 123 JONES LN or 72 MAIN STREET #32 and 72 MAIN STREET # 32.

***Part*** of the solution is to compare only the street numbers.  With a list that size it's unusual to have two different addresses with the same street number (e.g., 123 JONES LANE and 123 MAIN STREET).

**Caution:** You can't use VAL() to pull the street number.  Try it with 167 E 13 ST.  VBA sees that as 167^13 and will crash if you are outputting to Street_Num As Integer.  So you have to use a loop to pull the digits into a new string and stop at the first non-digit character.