# Excel function to lookup information

Tags: excel

I have an excel Workbook with sheets numbered according to months. Each sheet has a column for Artiste, Songtitle, Rights body.

I am now filling in the rights body for each song in every sheet.

Most of the sheets have the same artists and songs with a few additions.

What function can enable me to lookup the artiste and songtitle in the previous sheet and compare it to the artiste and songtitle in the current sheet and if it is a match, it fills in the Rights body value in the previous sheet into the current sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the VLOOKUP (http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) function.

See [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wH6jPVHnc9Q) for a YouTube video demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, i have actually used it, and it works. However, it returns wrong values in most cells

Comment: If you get wrong values then you need to set Range_lookup (the 4th value) to FALSE. If it's TRUE or omitted then VLOOKUP will use the closest match in case it doesn't find an exact match, if it's FALSE then it only finds exact matches (which I assume is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

The `lookup` or `vlookup` function is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match between lists where the data is not exactly the same, you could use fuzzy lookup code. Look here for details: [Matching similar but not exact text strings in Excel VBA projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects/13349597#13349597)

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP is fantastic as long as you are looking for exact matches. The TRUE / FALSE argument doesn't really serve the purpose you'd thought it serves. When you're looking for things that are not so black and white, you'd need some fuzzy logic here.

A quick example of where VLOOKUP falls short :

- Song name A = "Beethoven : Fidelio op.72"
- Song name B = "Beethoven : Fidelio opus 72"

Microsoft released a free add in to Excel (compatible with most recent versions) that enables fuzzy vlook up'ing. Get the file (add-in + documentation + example) here :

> > http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011