# EXCEL: Combining SUMIFS with multiple VLOOKUPs due to small variances in names

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumifs

Ok, this is going to be a difficult question to ask, but I'm gonna give it a try.

I have three sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) in one worksheet (Worksheet).

**Sheet1** contains ~100,000 rows with columns *Company (A)*, *Holding (B)*, *Product (C)*, *Year (D)*, *Spend (E)*.
**Sheet2** contains 100 rows with columns *Company (A)*, *Holding (B)*, *Product Spend in certain Year (C)*.
**Sheet3** contains 100 rows with columns *Company (A)*, *ID (B)*, *Variant1 (C)*, *Variant2 (D)*, *Variant3 (E)*.

What I want, is in **Sheet2** to calculate the *Product Spend in certain Year*. I've been able to do this as a test in **Sheet1** by using the function *SUMIFS*. So in **Sheet1** I used:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,"Fake Ltd",B:B,"Fake Holding",C:C,"Dog Food",D:D,"2011")
```

The problem is that the company names aren't the same in all sheets. I tried to solve it via a [FuzzyFind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects), but that is not working perfectly enough. So I decided to change my methods, and that's why **Sheet3** exists. This sheet contains all different name variants of one company in one row (similar to a relational database).

Now I need to use this *SUMIFS* function in **Sheet2** where the company name relates to all possible other company names in **Sheet3** so it can sum the company names that appear in **Sheet1** as if it were one company name. The column *Company* in **Sheet3** is the 'chosen' company name and also the one used in **Sheet2**. It's **Sheet1** that gives the problem.

So somehow I need to combine *SUMIFS* with *VLOOKUP* in **Sheet2**, but I am not sure how. Anyone any clues? I'll do my best to improve my question, I can imagine if I didn't do the best job explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Sheet1 is read-only, just add another column to Sheet1 in which you look up the proper company name from Sheet3. Then build your SUMIFS in Sheet2 based on this column.

If you're using Excel 2010/13, consider installing [Powerpivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bi/powerpivot.aspx) as an alternative. Here you only need to link the table from Sheet1 with the table from Sheet3 via the Company name column - and then produce a pivot that gives you all the aggregations you need!

Comment: That is stupidly brilliant (stupid for me and brilliant for you :-)) I'm using a Mac, so I'm not sure there is anything Powerful there.. I'm gonna give this a try for sure.

Comment: PowerPivot does not work on the Mac. :-(
Instead, create a pivot based on the extended Sheet1 - in the pivot put the real company name and the year as category fields and the spend as value field. Now you can have a `=GETPIVOTDATA(...` formula for each row in sheet2 - will also be really fast (but needs refresh if data updates)

Comment: Sounds good! Because you already answered my question and I have some other important issues in this model pending I wills solve them first. But once I get everything working, I'll have a look at this to improve speed, because the Mac isn't very fast, so thanks! Any speed improvements are welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is excel's array functionality.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx

For Sheet C, I'd suggest repeating the pattern:
  Company, Variant

That way, you can cross reference any and all companies that match in C without trying to compare against offset 1, 2, 3 ... n

You can then combine the results and use that to match against multiple criteria:

http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/

(the criteria is essentially the union of all rows that match both a company name and a year).

Once you've got the array of the rows that match, you can then apply your sumif over the top.

Comment: This sounds interesting, never heard of array formulas. I'll start reading then, thanks :-)

Comment: Although I think the INDEX/MATCH is necessary because SUMIFS already has multiple criteria options (unlike SUMIF).