# Find cells that have common values in vba

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am attempting to write a macro that will loop over a column and take each cell and find all the other cells that are approximate matches and move them to another spread sheet.  I thought of using the find method but I am unsure how to implement it for this.  I have pasted what I have done so far, which isn't much.  I am rather new to vba so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Extract()

Dim i As Long, count As Long, rng1 As Range

Set rng1 = Sheet1.Range(Range("N1"), Range("N1").End(xlDown))
count = 2
For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range(Range("N1"), Range("N1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

Sheet1.Cells(count, 14).Select


count = count + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "find all the other cells that are approximate matches" mean in practice?

Comment: Like, for example, if you have a cell that contains the word Alka-Seltzer and another that contained Alka-Seltzer Gold and another that contained Alka-Seltzer Heartburn it would group them together based on the common phrase "Alka-Seltzer."

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects

Answer (score 0):

This is a bare-bones solution to get you going.  Bare-bones because things like search string, search column, worksheets etc. are hard coded.  The 'matches' are placed in a worksheet called 'Matches' in the same 'position' as the 'Data' sheet (Col A) from which they have been extracted.

```
Sub findlikes()
Dim wsDat As Worksheet, wsMat As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String, firstAdd As String
Dim fndCell As Range
Dim srchCol As Long, numFnd As Long

Set wsDat = Sheets("Data")
Set wsMat = Sheets("Matches")
srchCol = 1  'Col A
strSearch = "Alka-Seltzer"

Set fndCell = wsDat.Columns(srchCol).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not fndCell Is Nothing Then
        firstAdd = fndCell.Address
        numFnd = 1
            Do
                wsMat.Range(fndCell.Address).Value = fndCell.Value
                Set fndCell = wsDat.Columns(srchCol).FindNext(fndCell)
                numFnd = numFnd + 1
            Loop While Not fndCell Is Nothing And fndCell.Address <> firstAdd
    Else
        MsgBox "Search String Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

This approach used the Find (and FindNext) methods that you mentioned in your original post.

Further references to these can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143(v=office.15).aspx).