# How to find similar string or text in a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In an excel Sheet, I have two colomns A & B (filled with text). I need to find for every same value in A, the part of the text in B that is similar. 
Example below:

[image]
the pictures named product_1000.jpg have in common "thecat_" which needs to be given in the third colomn.

How to find the colomn C automatically? (Excel formula or VBA). 
Note: My Table has around 40k lines.

Comment: Looks like a regex problem.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please verify [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and post what was tried.

Comment: Rather than a dynamic Regex, you can compare each String for equal values in column A, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13349597/7690982) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer thanks to the linked question of danieltakeshi's comment

```
Sub SerieNames()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For a = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(a, 1).Value = Cells(a - 1, 1).Value Then
        For i = 1 To Len(Cells(a - 1, 3))
            If (Left(Cells(a, 2), i) <> Left(Cells(a - 1, 3), i)) Then
            Cells(a, 3).Value = Left(Cells(a - 1, 3), i - 1)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next i
                If Cells(a, 3).Value = "" Then
                Cells(a, 3).Value = Cells(a - 1, 3).Value
                End If

    Else: Cells(a, 3).Value = Cells(a, 2).Value
    End If

Next a

End Sub
```

This Code is putting in the colomn C the longest common string starting from the left side. 
[image]
After that I only needed to find the last result of every serie in the colomn C to find my answer. This can be done with formula just by counting the shortest string result of C for every serie.

Note: The colomn A has to be sorted beforehand, otherwise the code will not work.