# VBA function InSTR - How to use asterisk (as any other charakter) in searched phrase?

Tags: excel, vba, asterisk

In Excel when we try to find some phrase we can put asterisk `*` inside as any other character. But how to do it inside VBA macro? For example below;
I want to find the secName by searching the value of firName with asterisk but id doesn't work. I suppose the problem is that VBA thinks that i want to find exactly `*` as normal character instead of anything.

```
Dim firName, secName As String

firName = "Da*"
secName = "Daniel"

search = InStr(1, secName, firName, vbTextCompare)

MsgBox (search)
```

Is it possible to use asterisk `*` in the way I described?

Comment: Use `Like`, or a regular expression. `Instr()` doesn't take wildcards.

Comment: `INSTR("DA")` will return `1` (as would `INSTR("DA*")` should such a beast exist, which it doesn) so with your example, a wildcard is not needed.

Comment: Please not that if you `Dim firName, secName As String` only the second variable is declared as `String` but the first one as `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim firName As String, secName As String`

Comment: I think you've chosen a bad example. Can you provide an example that is more close to what you are *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Actually I will have many Strings in one base which I will have to find in another base. The problem is some of them will be different in some ways (additional comas, dots or spaces). For example one String in the first base is "OFFICE CLUB, S.A." but in the second one "OFFICE CLUB SA" I would like to somehow use wildcards but according to John Coleman reply vba doesn't provide that solution. I can use "Like" but sometimes it will return more than one result which I want to avoid.
@Peh thanks for that tip, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

You can either do a FuzzySearch like: [Matching similar but not exact text strings in Excel VBA projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects), …

… or you can use the [The Levenshtein Distance](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/909002-levenshtein-approximate-string-matching) to find out how similar 2 strings are which is probably more accurate but needs `O(n*m)` time for calculation. So don't use it on very long strings.

```
Function Levenshtein(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Long
    Dim arrLev As Variant, intLen1 As Long, intLen2 As Long, i As Long
    Dim j As Long, arrStr1 As Variant, arrStr2 As Variant, intMini As Long

    intLen1 = Len(str1)
    ReDim arrStr1(intLen1 + 1)
    intLen2 = Len(str2)
    ReDim arrStr2(intLen2 + 1)
    ReDim arrLev(intLen1 + 1, intLen2 + 1)

    arrLev(0, 0) = 0
    For i = 1 To intLen1
        arrLev(i, 0) = i
        arrStr1(i) = Mid(str1, i, 1)
    Next i

    For j = 1 To intLen2
        arrLev(0, j) = j
        arrStr2(j) = Mid(str2, j, 1)
    Next j

    For j = 1 To intLen2
        For i = 1 To intLen1
            If arrStr1(i) = arrStr2(j) Then
                arrLev(i, j) = arrLev(i - 1, j - 1)
            Else
                intMini = arrLev(i - 1, j) 'deletion
                If intMini > arrLev(i, j - 1) Then intMini = arrLev(i, j - 1) 'insertion
                If intMini > arrLev(i - 1, j - 1) Then intMini = arrLev(i - 1, j - 1) 'deletion

                arrLev(i, j) = intMini + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

    Levenshtein = arrLev(intLen1, intLen2)
End Function
```

The smaller the returned number is the more similar are the strings.
For example:

```
Debug.Print Levenshtein("OFFICE CLUB, S.A.", "OFFICE CLUB SA")   'returns 3
Debug.Print Levenshtein("OFFICE CLUB, S.A.", "OFFICE CLUB S.A.") 'returns 1
```

The second strings are more similar than the first ones.