# Vlookup string/wildcard within string

Tags: excel, vba

How do I lookup a string in a string and populate corresponding column from different sheet?

For example, if Sheet 2 Column A has `Ford Ikon` and Column B has `Car` and Sheet 1 Column A has `Ford Fortuner`, I want to populate `Car` in Sheet 1 Column B by matching `Ford`.

I want to run this at scale for multiple attributes and rows and hence, looking for a macro

1. [Keyword Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlyLm.jpg)
2. [Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2LwK.jpg)

Comment: This is more of fuzzy matching rather wild card... I think. May be worth looking in to

Comment: Adding some more examples would be useful - it's difficult to derive all your matching rules from a single example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching similar but not exact text strings in Excel VBA projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects)

Comment: I added example data images. For example, for 'Seats for Ikon' in Input Data, I need macro to lookup into Keyword data and populate 'Car' by matching partial keyword from "Ford Ikon"