# How to find parts of words using index match in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

So I already have this formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table2[Company'#],MATCH("*"&[Store Address 1]&"*",Table2[AddressLine1],0)),"FALSE")`

so it works completely fine. But the thing is I was wondering if there is a better formula to read the cells completely

For example, in my `StoreAddress 1` I have something like `500 NORTHCENTER MALL` and in my `AddressLine1` I have something like `500 N CENTER MALL`

It returns false, and I'm assuming it's because it's not an exact match but logically it matches. So, I was wondering if there's another way to write this index match, rather than manually changing the cell to `TRUE`

Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: How would you express the logic that determines a match in all the possible variations of all addresses? What you want is a so-called fuzzy match, but that's not built into Excel. There are 3rd party tools, though, that do that.

Comment: As @teylyn suggested, you are looking for a fuzzy string match. There are multiple ways to do it, but keep in mind that fuzzy matches are not intelligent and there will be chances of errors. See this thread for a helpful fuzzy matching Excel UDF:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects