# Fuzzy string matching Excel

Tags: excel, vba, fuzzy-search

I am currently in need of a fuzzy string matching algorithm. I found one VBA code from this link given here: [Fuzzy Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects).

```
Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant
For Each cell In tbl_array
  str = cell
  For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
    If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
      a = a + 1
      cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid(cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
  Next i
  a = a - Len(cell)
  If a > b Then
    b = a
    Value = str
  End If
  a = 0
Next cell
FuzzyFind = Value
End Function
```

However, this gives you the match no matter how distant the "correct answer" is. Is there any way to implement that the functions gives "N/A" if it is, let's say, 4 characters or more away from the original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this and see if it's what you're after. It's loosely based off the one you have there.

EDIT: Did some more testing and found my original version not quite right. This should be better but it's near impossible to get something like this to work for every eventuality.

```
Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String

Dim i As Long, cell As Range, Matches As Long, LengthError As Long, _
FuzzyValue As String, FuzzyMatch As Long, L As String, C As String, MultipleReturns As Boolean

For Each cell In tbl_array
    Matches = 0
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        L = UCase(lookup_value)
        C = UCase(cell.Value)
        For i = 1 To Len(L)
            If InStr(Mid(L, i, Len(L) - i), Mid(C, i, 1)) > 0 Then
                Matches = Matches + 1
            Else
                Matches = Matches - 1
            End If
        Next i

        LengthError = Abs(Len(C) - Len(L))
        Matches = Matches - LengthError
        If Len(L) - Matches <= 4 And Matches >= FuzzyMatch Then
            If Matches = FuzzyMatch Then
                MultipleReturns = True
                Exit For
            End If
            FuzzyValue = cell.Value
            FuzzyMatch = Matches
        End If
    End If
Next
If FuzzyValue <> "" Then
    If MultipleReturns = True Then
        FuzzyFind = "N/A (Multiple Returns)"
    Else
        FuzzyFind = FuzzyValue
    End If
Else
    FuzzyFind = "N/A"
End If

End Function
```