# Fuzzy Match in excel/vba

Tags: vba, fuzzy-logic

I just wanted to know if the following is possible using fuzzy match in excel:

I have a database in excel that I am building a search engine for. The database is in a table format. My data involves 200 hyperlinks of excel files, so there’s 200 rows of data. So my data has specific data about each of these excel files like the topic of what these files contain. I want to build a search engine so someone can search for a specific topic.

I want the search engine to involve fuzzy matching so something can be typed wrong and a result can still be found from the dynamic table/database. It’s dynamic since there might be more hyperlinks added to the database in excel. I just want to know if this kind of search engine is possible because I have not been able to find any answer on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching similar but not exact text strings in Excel VBA projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291313/matching-similar-but-not-exact-text-strings-in-excel-vba-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Excel supports fuzzy lookup. This is an AddIn

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011